# Location with GPS_PROVIDER

Tags: android, android-location, android-maps, android-gps

Sorry, I'm a beginner in android.
I have to save when a car parks using a service.
To do this I'm using LocationManager with GPS_PROVIDER to monitor the speed of the car.
I am using requestLocationUpdates but when the machine stops onLocationChanged it is no longer called so I can not get the speed, understand that it is stationary and save the parking space.
How could I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want continued updates while stopped you need to ensure 'minDistance' is not preventing updates.  It is passed to your 'requestLocationUpdates' call.  Try setting the value to 0.  However this will also have a negative impact on battery life.  I would also suggest looking into the location APIs provided by Google Play Services instead of using the LocationManager.